# Wordpress dashboard is not loading properly

Tags: php, wordpress

My site's dashboard and its other options are not loading properly but my site is working fine except some css styling. I've checked it on two systems. I have cleared my cache also I have tried that 'do plugin disabled by renaming and find issue' solution from FTP but no results.
[dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaopI.png)

Comment: Please post your question with codes.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can enable debugging of the WordPress website. Refer the URL below to check how to enable debugging

URL:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

2. After enabling debugging debug.log file will be created in the wp-content folder where you can get actual issue details so you can get idea to fix it